# Trouble using MySQL select queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables "posts" and "relations"

I am omitting the non-essential columns from my tables for the sake of brevity.

"Posts"

```
post_id | user_id | privacy
```

"Relations"

```
rel_id | sender | recipient | status
```

Here Is what I am trying to accomplish:

Grab all posts where the user_id in the posts table  = the recipient in the relations table and skip the posts where the status in the relations table is 1 and the post privacy is 2.

Now, I would also, at the same time like to grab all of the posts from the users table where user_id = $user_id

I have tried using a join with an OR statement in my query. It doesn't work right. I think the problem is that I am setting the p.user_id = r.recipient in my join and the only time the user's id is in the recipient column is when SOMEONE ELSE is if following (status = 1) or friends (status = 2) with the current user.

My current MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT post_id, user_id, privacy
FROM posts p
JOIN relations r ON p.user_id = r.recipient
AND (r.sender = '".$user_id."')
AND NOT (r.status = 1 AND p.privacy = 2)
OR (p.post_id = '".$user_id."')
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC
```

So I think I need to use a UNION but it isn't working at all. I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM posts p
JOIN relations r ON p.user_id = r.recipient
AND (r.sender = 1)
AND NOT (r.status = 1 AND p.privacy = 2)
ORDER BY p.post_id DESC
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the logic is right for the `union`, I think this is the query that you want:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
WHERE user_id = '".$user_id."'
UNION 
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p JOIN
     relations r
     ON p.user_id = r.recipient AND r.sender = '".$user_id."' AND
        NOT (r.status = 1 AND p.privacy = 2)
ORDER BY post_id DESC;
```

Notice three changes:

1. The second query selects only fields from the posts table.
2. The second query is comparing to the variable `$user_id` instead of the hardcoded `1` (I think this is a typo in the original post).
3. The `order by` clause doesn't use a table alias.  There is no definition of `p.post_id` in the *overall* query, only in the subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `UNION` or `UNION ALL` you're merging two result sets: the ones for the `SELECT` operations on each side of the `UNION`.  The two result sets in your question are not conformable: that is, they have different numbers of columns.

This is because you have used `SELECT *` rather than `SELECT item, item, item`. `SELECT *` from your second result set contains all the columns of both the `posts` and `relations` tables, whereas only the `posts` table's columns appear in your first result set.